# AWSのEC2での容量不足について

Tags: linux, aws, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

AWSのEC2(Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu) Version 24.0)を使用しています。
自分自身ではそれほど大容量データを保存しているつもりはないのですが（せいぜい5~20GB）、73GBあるはずの/dev/xvda1の容量が100%になってしまっています。
最初は本当に73GB使っているかと思い、85GBのボリュームを追加し/dev/xvdf（data2）でマウントし、保存していたデータの多くを移行したのですが、data2は余裕がありますが、/dev/xvda1の方がすぐに100%になってしまいます。

インスタンスの再起動をすると数百MB～数GBは空きが出るのですが、一度、大容量データの保存に失敗すると、それ以降（保存しかけたデータを削除しても）ほぼ空きがない状態になってしまいます。

du -hsでフォルダごとに見てみると、home>ubuntu>anaconda3>envの容量が大きく、20種類くらいのフレームワークに対応したフォルダ（例えばそのうち1つは3GB）があるようなのですが、例えば使わないライブラリの削除などはしても良いでしょうか。

df -hの結果は以下です。

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             30G     0   30G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.0G  8.9M  6.0G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       73G   71G  2.3G  97% /
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/xvdf        84G   13G   67G  17% /data2
tmpfs           6.0G  4.0K  6.0G   1% /run/user/1000
```

df -iの結果は以下です。

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           7858007     333 7857674    1% /dev
tmpfs          7859983     464 7859519    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     9600000 1224734 8375266   13% /
tmpfs          7859983       1 7859982    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          7859983       3 7859980    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          7859983      16 7859967    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       12829   12829       0  100% /snap/core/7917
/dev/loop1       12827   12827       0  100% /snap/core/7713
/dev/loop2          15      15       0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1455
/dev/loop3          15      15       0  100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1480
/dev/xvdf      5570560      98 5570462    1% /data2
tmpfs          7859983       6 7859977    1% /run/user/1000
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 例えば使わないライブラリの削除などはしても良いでしょうか。

使われてないのが明確なら削除してもいいと思いますが、影響がわからないので、とりあえずキャッシュを消してみるのも良いかもです。

```
conda clean --all
```

Comment: take88様  ご回答誠にありがとうございます。返信が遅くなり申し訳ございません。頂いたコードでキャッシュを消し、ライブラリは使われていないのが明確だったため削除しました。結果的に数GB節約することができました。本当にありがとうございました。